# How do i Dynamically change a rad button name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a little form in which the users select their gender. I have a script that creates a new line for additional users but the problem is that as this code clones the previous element and the radio button name attribute is the same as before making the gender selection name unusable, is there a way to change the radio buttons name when adding a new row so the group will be different to the previous groups name.

```js
function addRow() {
  var radName = document.getElementsByName('gender2').value;
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var row = document.getElementById('lastRow');
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
  table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tableDiv">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr id="firstRow">
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Forname(S)</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td class="gender">Male</td>
        <td class="gender">Female</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="lastRow">
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" id="buttonOne" onclick="addRow()" value="+" />
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Since you are cloning the row which has an id - you are also cloning that id - meaning that on top of your issues with the radio button you will end up with multiple instances of tr's with the same id.

Given that you know what is to be cloned (ie - the structure of the table row / cells within it and the inputs required) - why don't you create a row with new id's / names and simply append that to the table. This would allow you to create new trs and within the tds the required inputs and you could then create unique names as part of the process, as well as unique id's for each appended tr

Answer (score 4):

- Assign `name` property for child elements of `cloned` node.
- Use [**`querySelector`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to select element.
- Use [**`querySelectorAll('#myTable tr')`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) selector to get the `length` of the `tr` elements.

```js
function addRow() {
  var radName = document.getElementsByName('gender2').value;
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var row = document.getElementById('lastRow');
  var newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
  var index = --document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr').length;
  newRow.querySelector('[value="Male"]').name = 'gender' + index;
  newRow.querySelector('[value="Male"]').name = 'gender' + index;
  table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr id="firstRow">
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>Forname(S)</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>City</td>
      <td class="gender">Male</td>
      <td class="gender">Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Surname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Age" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="City" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Male" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Female" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Surname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Age" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="City" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Male" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Female" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="lastRow">
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Surname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="Age" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder="City" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Male" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Female" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="buttonOne" onclick="addRow()" value="+" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to clone the line and make changes to names.

You should generate the HTML code for the row and hanlding the correct name directly.

Here is an example snippet:

```js
var idx = 0;

window.onload = addRow;

function addRow() {
  var rowHTML = '<td><input placeholder="Surname" /></td><td><input placeholder="Forename(S)" /></td><td><input placeholder="Age" /></td><td><input placeholder="City" /></td><td><input class="gender" name="gender' + idx + '" type="radio" value="Male" /></td><td><input class="gender" name="gender' + idx + '" type="radio" value="Female" /></td>';
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.innerHTML = rowHTML;
  
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  table.appendChild(row);
  idx++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tableDiv">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr id="firstRow">
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Forname(S)</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td class="gender">Male</td>
        <td class="gender">Female</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  <input type="submit" id="buttonOne" onclick="addRow()" value="+" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works nicely, thanks a lot. I just need to make the first row visible on load, cheers mate

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ thanks for the update much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Done this with JQuery, Try this:

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var newRow = $("#myTable tr:last").clone()
  var name = $(newRow).find("input[type='radio']").attr("name");
  var newVal = parseInt(name.match(/\d+/)) + 1;
  $(newRow).find("input[type='radio']").attr("name", 'gender' + newVal);
  table.append(newRow);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tableDiv">

    <table id="myTable">
      <tr id="firstRow">
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>Forname(S)</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td class="gender">Male</td>
        <td class="gender">Female</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender0" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender1" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="lastRow">
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Surname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Forename(S)" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="Age" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input placeholder="City" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Male" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="gender" name="gender2" type="radio" value="Female" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" id="buttonOne" onclick="addRow()" value="+" />
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: this works great too, good to have a javascript AND jQuery versions thanks Govind

Comment: The OP seems happy about this answer, but *typically* don't provide jQuery answers to JavaScript questions. You may well be voted down for doing this. Also FYI @Matti_Leeds if your happy to have a jquery solution it's good to say this and add the appropriate tag

Comment: Matti_Leeds used jQuery in html thats why I've used jQuery, I'll take care from next time. Thanks